# Conver english content into gujarati in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to develop one module.In which user can type question which would be displaying in gujarati Lang & it has to store in database.So i can view this question in gujrati.All this thing i want to do in php & mysql.So please help me regarding same..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Translate API](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/) to convert and then can store the converted text to your DB.

```
<?php
    $apiKey = '<paste your API key here>';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=' . $apiKey;

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     //We want the result to be saved into variable, not printed out
    $response = curl_exec($handle);                         
    curl_close($handle);

    print_r(json_decode($response, true));
?>
```